# SQL using FOR XML PATH to do a group by and concatenation

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am using `FOR XML PATH` to do a group concatenation however it is not grouping the colors as the final result.

```
select distinct 
    m1.inv_mast_uid,
    m1.short_code,
    m1.class_id1,
    m1.class_id5,
    stuff((select distinct '' + ud.color + ', '
           from inv_mast m2
           join inv_mast_ud as ud on ud.inv_mast_uid = m2.inv_mast_uid
           where m1.inv_mast_uid = m2.inv_mast_uid
           for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 0, '') as colors
from 
    inv_mast as m1
```

TABLE inv_mast

```
inv_mast_uid    short_code  class_id1   class_id5
-------------------------------------------
469             EPHESUS     EPHESUS     10X16
470             EPHESUS     EPHESUS     10X16
471             EPHESUS     EPHESUS     13X13
472             EPHESUS     EPHESUS     13X13
707             EPHESUS     EPHESUS     NULL
```

TABLE inv_mast_ud

```
inv_mast_uid    color
-------------------------------------------
469             Brown
470             Ivory
471             Brown
472             Ivory
707             Brown
```

Current results:

```
short_code  class_id1   class_id5   colors
-------------------------------------------
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     NULL        Brown, 
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     10X16       Brown, 
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     10X16       Ivory, 
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     13X13       Brown, 
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     13X13       Ivory,
```

Desired results

```
short_code  class_id1   class_id5   colors
-------------------------------------------------
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     NULL        Brown, Ivory
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     10X16       Brown, Ivory
EPHESUS     EPHESUS     13X13       Brown, Ivory
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR) (KB4532095) - 12.0.6118.4 (X64)   Dec 12 2019 21:46:15   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Answer (score 0):

While asking a question you need to provide a DDL and sample data population. So I had to come up with it on the fly and based on my imagination.

It is not clear what is your primary key.

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (short_code VARCHAR(10), class_id1 VARCHAR(10), class_id5 VARCHAR(10), color VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl (short_code, class_id1, class_id5,  color) VALUES
('EPHESUS','EPHESUS', NULL  ,'Brown'),
('EPHESUS','EPHESUS','10X16','Brown'),
('EPHESUS','EPHESUS','10X16','Ivory'),
('EPHESUS','EPHESUS','13X13','Brown'),
('EPHESUS','EPHESUS','13X13','Ivory');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(2) = ', ';

SELECT short_code, class_id1, class_id5 
   , STUFF((SELECT @separator + CAST(color AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [text()]
         FROM @tbl AS O
         WHERE O.short_code = C.short_code 
         AND COALESCE(O.class_id5, '') = COALESCE(C.class_id5, '')
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS colorList
FROM @tbl AS c
GROUP BY short_code, class_id1, class_id5;
```

**Output**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| short_code | class_id1 | class_id5 |  colorList  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| EPHESUS    | EPHESUS   | NULL      | Brown       |
| EPHESUS    | EPHESUS   | 10X16     | Brown,Ivory |
| EPHESUS    | EPHESUS   | 13X13     | Brown,Ivory |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```